# How to mimic functionality of Access specifiers inside a python class?

Tags: python

Python is not providing access specifiers inside the classes .
Is there any way to mimic the features of private functions inside python classes like other programming languages like ruby and java do ?

Comment: In general, anobject is considered private if it is prefixed with underscore (double for function) like this: `_private_var` or `__private_func`. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python

Comment: But note that they're not really private..

Comment: But even though we specify __ the functionality of access specifiers is not provided . Is there any way to implement functionality using decorators or properties ?

Comment: really python thought says you shouldnt really need or want private variables ... they provide some conventions but no such thing as truly private variables